# jpa - what happen to a persisted entity updated and detached

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a persisted entity (session) inside a transaction (managed by entity manager).
I do some changes to that entity or to related ones (reached using getter).
The number of object related to the session object could become huge, so I would like to save the current object (and all related in cascade), free the memory and reload the entity (quite all related objects are loaded lazy) to continue work with
That's the way I'm planning to work

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
function Session manageSession(Long sessionId) {
   Session session = null;
   if (sessionId == null) {
     session = new Session()
     .....Setting fields...
     em.persist(session);
   } else {
     session = em.find(Session.class,sessionId);
   }
   List<Long> objectIdToBeLinked = getRemainingUnlinkedObj();
   for (Long id : objectIdToBeLinked) {
      createRelatedObj(session, id) //here activities the create more and more objs to be linked to session)
      if (checkMemory) { //where checkmemory return true if we have no more mem space
        em.flush;
        Long sessionId = session.getId();
        session = null;
        manageSession(sessionId)M    
      }
   }
}
```

What happen to the entities created (the session and the related too) when, after flushing, I set session to null: will them saved? will the GC free the memory? and when I reload it (with the find), do the EM reload it from scratch (not using the previous one)?

Comment: The EntityManager has a reference to any managed entity until it is either cleared via em.clear(), or sometime after it is closed (and with EclipseLink, once it too is garbage collected).  If you want to be sure it is released, call em.clear after your flush.

Comment: @Chris Can you please post your comment as answer so that this question no longer appears as unanswered? Thank you